# android progressbar at sending file

Tags: android

hi im working on an android messenger and i need to show the progress bar when sending and receiving files. could anyone help? for instance this is how i send the file,

```
@Override
    public boolean sendFile(String path,String ip, int port) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    try {


        String[] str = ip.split("\\.");

        byte[] IP = new byte[str.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

            IP[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str[i]);


        }
        Socket socket = getSocket(InetAddress.getByAddress(IP), port);
        if (socket == null) {
            Log.i("SO sendFILE","null");

            return false;
        }

        Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-1");
        File  f = new File(path);


        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );

        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(f);
        Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-2");
        byte [] buffer  = new byte [(int)f.length()];
        System.out.println("SO sendFile f.length();" + f.length());
        int bytesRead =0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            System.out.println("SO sendFile" + bytesRead);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        fileIn.close();
        Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-3");






    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;           
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //  Toast.makeText(this, "Lvbvhhging...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return true;        
}
    }
```

now where do i put the bar and how do i do that inorder to show the user the progress?

Comment: i would say you update your progressbar inside your while loop ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this ::**

```
 private class xyz extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(tranning.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            this.dialog.show();
            // put your code which preload with processDialog  
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // put your code here
Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-1");
        File  f = new File(path);


        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );

        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(f);
        Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-2");
        byte [] buffer  = new byte [(int)f.length()];
        System.out.println("SO sendFile f.length();" + f.length());
        int bytesRead =0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            System.out.println("SO sendFile" + bytesRead);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        fileIn.close();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
              this.dialog.dismiss();

            }   
        }
    }
```

**and use this in main  ::**

```
    new xyz().execute();
```

Comment: Thanx for the kind words. But how you be a fan?

Comment: well u see the thing is, i call the sendFile method from another class. like my messaging activity has a chat box right, so i click the menu and select the sendfile option.now the sendfile method is called that contains the code that i put in my question. now do i need to make another class for that sendfile method to hold ? or do i just put the code that u suggested as it is?

Comment: fan >> mean of programming world & with your post

Comment: @hardy.exe you can continue with as it is

Comment: okay thank you very much. one quick question : where do i call xyz().execute? the UI from where m calling the sendFile method?

Comment: please have a look at my edited question. this is actually the complete code.

Comment: hi, please could you show me how to add the bar now? i have a method inside the xyz class now..?? anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Do your file sending task in `separate thread` not in the UI thread. When you start this thread call your progress dialog and remvove it from thread when you are done using `Handler`.

For Handler you can refer this doc:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 0):

```
myProgressBar.setProgress(0);
while ((bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            //get the previous value of progress bar 
            int old_value = myProgressBar.getProgress();
            //calculate how much did you read from the file
            int new_read =(int)( ((float) f.length() / bytesRead) )*100 ) ;
            //add the new read to the old_value
            int value = new_read+old_value;
            myProgressBar.setProgress(value); 
            System.out.println("SO sendFile" + bytesRead);
        }
```

see [this link](http://guides.wikinut.com/Progress-Bar-On-Android/4ws2d1y7/) for how to construct a ProgressBar in android